# ¿Por qué se superponen elementos del main en el footer?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

¿Por qué está pasando esto?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo negro de abajo es el footer de la página, es decir, quiero que el alto de la sección main aumente conforme hayan más videos, pero se superponen.

El componente que contiene estos estilos es:

```
{/** VIDEOS */}
<main>
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "space-between",
          }}
        >
          <div className={styles.search_video_list}>
            {videos.map((video) => {
              return (
                <StandardThumbnail
                  key={video.id}
                  onClick={() => router.push(`${video.id}`)}
                  locked={false}
                  selected={false}
                  image={
                    "/assets/images/lol-logo.png"
                    //video.image
                  }
                  title={video.title}
                  duration={video.duration.toString()}
                />
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
        {/** VIDEOS */}
</main>
```

Os dejo CSS a ver si alguien lo ve:

```
.main {
    margin: 160px auto 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;

    h1 {
        @include center
    }
}
.search_video_list {
    @include center;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
    gap: 6% 10%; 
    grid-template-areas: 
        ". . ."
        ". . ."
        ". . ."; 
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué tal si quitas el `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;`? No creo lo necesites. Creo que puedes quitar hasta el `grid-template-areas:`, con las columnas basta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes resolver cambiando el `gap`. Debes usar píxeles en vez de %.

Prueba usando:

```
gap: 6px 10px;
```